# ExpressJS parameterised nested routes

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following route config in ExpressJS:

```
router.route('/api/test/:param').get(route.doSomething);
router.route('/api/test/path/:a/:b').get(route.doSomethingElse);
```

The problem is that if I now call the /api/test/path/bla/blabla route that matches the one before because of the :param parameter (so :param will be ‘/path/bla/blabla’ which is really not what I want.

How I can specify such routes without reordering my route definitions?

Comment: Why don't you want to reorder your routes? The order *is* important.

Comment: I'm curious to see if there's another solution to this problem.